# Change permissions of file in the download folder

Tags: android

Is it possible to change the permissions for files saved in the generic download folder? (i.e. where the browser sends downloads.) I've tried to use the file methods `setReadable` and `setWritable` to make the files I've downloaded viewable but the method returns false. I'm assuming this is because I don't have root access.

If the user uses a file explorer directly on the phone they can see the files, but if they hook their phone to the computer the files cannot be seen.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The "generic download folder" (`Downloads` on external storage, by default) is read/write for users, unless your device is terribly broken.

Comment: @CommonsWare That is what I thought initially, so when I first wrote the code I didn't bother to set permissions. But for whatever reason I can only see the files if I use a file explorer directly on the phone. Out of curiosity I saved the downloaded file in the Android folder and I could actually see it from the computer file explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've tried to use the file methods setReadable and setWritable to make the files I've downloaded viewable but the method returns false.

Perhaps you did not index them with `MediaScannerConnection`, or perhaps your computer caches the results of the MTP connection to the device.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was my exact problem. I didn't know about registering with `MediaScannerConnection`

Comment: @Pinsickle: Yeah, you didn't need to do that with Android 1.x/2.x, but you do with Android 3.0+. More history at http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/08/31/mtp-external-storage.html

Answer (score 1):

Some file systems including SD cards do not allow permission changes. The generic download folder most probably is on one of that kind.

Try changing the USB computer connection to Mass storage, that should fix the problem.